# Currency conversion confusion

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I buy 1 unit of stock at **USD=55.48** when **USD-INR=66.40**, spending **INR=3684.02**
I sell 1 unit of stock at **USD=54.60** when **USD-INR=65.44**, gettingbk  **INR=3573.13**

My Loss in **USD=0.88** and in **INR=110.89** giving *USD-INR=126* instead of expected value of *65.44*. 
What is the mistake here?

Comment: The buy was $55.46\times66.40=3683.872.$

The sale was $54.60\times65.44=3573.024$

The difference is $110.848$.   I know that's not the big problem but the little math may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in that the loss of 110.89 in INR is not entirely due to the stock price decline, it also includes a portion due to the currency appreciation. You need to remove that part before implying the exchange rate.

The part of the loss due to the currency change is

$$\frac{66.40-65.44}{66.40}\times 3684.02=53.36$$